# How can I create a shortcode that shows a list of categories on the single product page?

Tags: shortcode

This may seem simple but I want to create a shortcode called [woo_prod_categories] that will simply display a list of the categories of a specific product on the single product page (each linked to their category page).

I did this for the SKU:

```
function display_woo_cat() {

global $product;
return $product->get_sku();


}
add_shortcode( 'woo_prod_category', 'display_woo_cat' );
```

I can tried the shortcodes I found in the WooCommerce documentation but they just show all the categories. I know there are ways to do this via standard single product pages turning on options in the WooCommerce settings. I am trying to make a custom single product page.  I am using elementor and I know there are elements that can do this. I just want a list of categories that are linked back to the category page that are produced by a shortcode.

I want to put this shortcode in a table so it matches the meta data like attributes, dimensions, etc.

Does anyone have any idea how I can do this quick and easy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
function woo_prod_categories() {
    if ( is_product() ) {
        global $post;
        $product_cats = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat' );
        
        if ( ! empty( $product_cats ) && ! is_wp_error( $product_cats ) ) {
            $cat_links = array();

            foreach ( $product_cats as $product_cat ) {
                $cat_links[] = '<a href="' . get_term_link( $product_cat->term_id, 'product_cat' ) . 
                '">' . $product_cat->name . '</a>';
            }

            return implode( ', ', $cat_links );
        }
    }

    return '';
}

add_shortcode( 'woo_prod_categories', 'woo_prod_categories' );
```

The function checks if the current page is a product page and then retrieves the product categories (using `get_the_terms()` function). It then generates a linked list of these categories which is then returned by the shortcode. The categories are separated by commas.

Comment: This is great! Thank you, thank you! Is there anyway for me to set them in the order I have set in the categories section of WooCommerce or does it have to be alphabetical?

Comment: Exactly where should this code be added? It's for a regular page, not a post.